# Unexpected T_STRING in for loop

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++){
$var_b[$i]  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $i .' day', strtotime($today)));
$var2_b[$i]_name = date('d', strtotime($var_b[$i]));
```

Error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in XXX\index.php on line XX

---

EDIT:

I put the curly brackets, the error message line on this one:

```
$var2_b[$i] = date('d', strtotime($var_b[$i]));
```

Comment: Its best to use a validator, so you avoid posting questions that are mearly missing a }.  Komodo Edit is a great free syntax checker that you can use. http://www.activestate.com/komodo_edit/

Comment: Question title reminds me of Yahoo Answers: Every question on that site is actually a statement with a question mark tacked on to the end.

Answer (score 3):

Where is your closing `}`? (Also remember that array indexing starts with 0)

Answer (score 3):

You need the closing curly brace `}` for your `for` loop.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $var_b[$i]  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $i .' day', strtotime($today)));
  $var2_b[$i] = date('d', strtotime($var_b[$i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing curly bracket.

}

Answer (score 0):

Please close your for loop's curly brace...

Also was the error on one of the lines in the code provided?

Comment: His code runs fine in a test script - gotta be the curly brace.

Comment: yeah, i have edit and include the line of errors, i also confuse, since everone said my code is correct, then what does the error message keep appear??

Comment: Your code is NOT correct. You are missing a closing curly brace at the end of the loop... for() { ...code here... }

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, adding the closing brace, and it doesn't report an error.
Are you sure the line you changed to XX is in the code you supplied?